# Why does TextChanged fire when a RichEditBox gains focus?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, textchanged

I have a RichEditBox in a C# Windows Runtime app. I have set it to set a Boolean flag `IsFileUpToDate` to false on TextChanged like so:

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsFileUpToDate != false)
    {
        IsFileUpToDate = false;
    }
}
```

When the page is first navigated to, `IsFileUpToDate` should be set to true. I have set it like so:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    IsFileUpToDate = true;
}
```

However, the RichEditBox gains focus immediately when the page loads, and this seems to be causing it set the Boolean to false even though the text hasn't been changed. Why is it doing this? How can I rewrite these commands so that the Boolean is reliably set?

Answer (score 0):

RichEditBox is getting it's text changed on when it is loaded
you can have another flag to make sure it won't change yours on the fisrt time

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsFirstload)
    {
        IsFirstLoad = false;
        return;
    }

    if (IsFileUpToDate != false)
    {
        IsFileUpToDate = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing this bug as well, and it's not simply when the RichEditBox is loaded. Instead, it's on every time the RichEditBox gains focus. As a result, this solution won't work.